# trouble coding links which insert search values into ransack form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, search, ransack

I've coded in a page in which data from a database is pulled and subsequently when I click on what is displayed it enters a corresponding value into the search function on the application and displays the results, the code can be seen below:

course view:

```
<!-- Index of all Courses -->
<% provide(:title, "Course") %>

<!--containers for design/layout --> 
<div class = "signinstyle">
  <div class = "row">
    <!--Page information --> 


      <%= form_tag(degree_new_path, :method => "get", id: "search-data") do %>


            <table border="1" class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Courses</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <% @ads.each do |degree| %>
                    <tr>


                 <td> <%= link_to degree.cname, keyword_search_path(search: degree.cname) %>                 



                  </td>
                </tr>
                <% end %>
              </tbody>
            </table>
      <%= submit_tag "Select" %>
      <% end %>

    <!--closing the design/layout containers --> 
    </div>
</div>


degree controller (the above view is within this):
class Degree < ActiveRecord::Base

  def Degree.search(search)
    where("cname LIKE ? OR ucas LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
  end
end
```

search controller (as I use my keyword search in the view):

```
  def keyword_search
    @search = Degree.all.select(:uname, :cname, :ucas, :duration, :qualification, :entry).distinct.order(id: :ASC)
    if params[:search]
      @search_degree = Degree.search(params[:search]).order('cname ASC')
    end
  end

  def course
    @select = Degree.all.select(:uname, :cname, :ucas, :duration, :qualification, :entry).distinct.order(id: :ASC)
    if params[:search]
      @select_degree = Degree.search(params[:search])
    end
  end
```

I'm trying to replicate the above code so I can click on similar links which will enter data into the ransack search function I have but have been unable to do so, if anybody could help me out it would be appreciated. Below is the code I'm currently trying to get to work:

Searches controller:

```
  def adsearch
    @adsearch = Degree.ransack(params[:q])
    @data = @adsearch.result
    @adsearch.build_condition if @adsearch.conditions.empty?
    @adsearch.build_sort if @adsearch.sorts.empty?
  end
```

the view file:

```
<!-- Index of all Courses -->
<% provide(:title, "Course") %>

<!--containers for design/layout --> 
<div class = "signinstyle">
  <div class = "row">
    <!--Page information --> 


      <%= form_tag(degree_new_path, :method => "get", id: "search-data") do %>


            <table border="1" class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Courses</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <% @ads.each do |degree| %>
                    <tr>


                  <td> <%= link_to degree.subject_group, adsearch_path(name: ucas & value: degree.ucas_letter) %>




                  </td>
                </tr>
                <% end %>
              </tbody>
            </table>
      <%= submit_tag "Select" %>
      <% end %>

    <!--closing the design/layout containers --> 
    </div>
</div>
```

With the last two exerts of code it displays what I'm asking it to display on the initial view but doesn't enter the value I wish it to enter into the ransack search and as such doesn't create a search when clicked upon like the first example does.